# Having issues converting date from XML feed to usable date

Tags: php, datetime

I am consuming an XML feed that dumps an attribute of `dateacquired` and the date that is `"2014-3-28 6:08 AM"`.. I am needing to use this attribute and it's date in my Mongo DB, but I am not sure how to convert it to a date that is usable (e.g. for date based queries).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to translate the date into a DateTime object and then alter its format use [`DateTime::format()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-n-d h:i A', '2014-3-28 6:08 AM');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It's been a while since I have written PHP